# Getting the data of the parent view in onclick listener of a button

Tags: javascript, html

I am having a HTML file.

```
<div id="parent">
  <h1 id="name">giri</h1>
  <button id="btn">Send The Name</button>
</div>
```

And I am having an onclick listener in the script for button click.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.addEventListener('click',function(e)
        {
            e = e || window.event;
            var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
            console.log("ENTERED NAME=="+?????????); 
            console.log("value of the element clicked== "+target.innerHTML);

            console.log(target);//<-- this is the element that was clicked
        }, false);
</script>
```

How can i get the entered name in the click listener?

Comment: `document.getElementById("name").innerText;` since you're using ID's I assume you know you can only use these one time in a document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```js
window.onload = function () {
  document.querySelector("#btn").onclick = function () {
    console.log(this.parentNode.querySelector("#name").innerHTML);
  };
};
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <h1 id="name">giri</h1>
  <button id="btn">Send The Name</button>
</div>
```

The above code makes real sense if you have multiple instances with contextual data needed. Let me give an example for that.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var btns = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
  for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    (function(i) {
      btns[i].onclick = function() {
        console.log(this.parentNode.querySelector(".name").innerHTML);
      };
    })(i);
  }
};
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <h1 class="name">giri</h1>
  <button class="btn">Send The Name</button>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <h1 class="name">praveen</h1>
  <button class="btn">Send The Name</button>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <h1 class="name">kumar</h1>
  <button class="btn">Send The Name</button>
</div>
```

Comment: @giridharan Welcome. Have a nice day.